# Query IN() not working as intended

Tags: mysql

If I run the query:

```
SELECT board.id, board.name
FROM board
INNER JOIN group_assoc ON group_id
IN (
"4,9,12,15,18,21,22,55,57,83,84,86,89,92,95,98,104,105"
)
AND group_assoc.board_id = board.id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = board.category_id
AND category.forum_id =2
```

I get a different result than

```
SELECT board.id, board.name
FROM board
INNER JOIN group_assoc ON group_id = 9
AND group_assoc.board_id = board.id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = board.category_id
AND category.forum_id =2
```

Is it only pulling boards that can be viewed by all groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values in "IN" are integers, don't use double quotation marks (" "), like this

```
SELECT board.id, board.name
FROM board
INNER JOIN group_assoc ON group_id
IN (
4,9,12,15,18,21,22,55,57,83,84,86,89,92,95,98,104,105
)
AND group_assoc.board_id = board.id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = board.category_id
AND category.forum_id =2
```

And if the values are strings, use double quotation marks for each string.

```
SELECT board.id, board.name
FROM board
INNER JOIN group_assoc ON group_id
IN (
"4121213","9434345443","12545454"
)
AND group_assoc.board_id = board.id
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = board.category_id
AND category.forum_id =2
```

Comment: Because they are integers, MySQL (and most other databases) will perform implicit data type conversion between INT and string based data types, depending on the data type of the column being compared to.  So if `group_id` is INT, the IN values will be considered INTs.

Answer (score 1):

Try `IN (4,9,12,...)`